# pandas GroupBy plotting two lines for each group on one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I've been struggling to plot the results of the GroupBy on three columns.
I have the data on the different absences (AbsenceType) of employees (Employee) over 3 years (MonthYear). I would like to plot in one plot, how many absences of a particular type an employee had in each month-year. I have only two employees in the example, but there are more in the data as well as more month-year values.

*Create data*

```
data = {'Employee': ['ID1', 'ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2','ID2','ID2','ID2','ID2', 'ID2'],
'MonthYear': ['201708', '201601','201601','201708','201710','201801','201801', '201601', '201601', '201705', '201705', '201705', '201810', '201811', '201705'],
'AbsenceType': ['0210', '0210','0250','0215','0217','0260','0210', '0210', '0210', '0260', '0250', '0215', '0217', '0215', '0250']}

columns = ['Employee','MonthYear','AbsenceType']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Then I map each of the codes of the AbsenceType into two categories: Sick or Injury.

```
df['SickOrInjury'] =df['AbsenceType'].replace({'0210':'Sick', '0215':'Sick', '0217':'Sick', '0250':'Injury', '0260':'Injury'})
```

What I want to achieve is the following groupby:

```
test = df.groupby(['Employee', 'MonthYear', 'SickOrInjury'])['SickOrInjury'].count()
```

But, when I try to plot it, it does not fully show what I want. So far I managed to get to the stage:

```
df.groupby(['Employee', 'MonthYear', 'SickOrInjury'])['SickOrInjury'].count().unstack('SickOrInjury', fill_value=0).plot()
plt.show()
```

[test plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTzO3.png)
However, employee's ID are shown on the X axis and not in the legend.

What I want to have is something like this:
[desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pbKQ.jpg)
I would like to have time on the X axis and the count for each absence type (sick or injury) on the Y axis. There should be two different types of lines (e.g. solid and dashed) for each absence type and different colors for each employee (e.g. black and red).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think unstacking is the right approach to fill missing values but you should probably convert `MonthYear` to date and resample by month. You can then plot your dataframe using `seaborn.lineplot`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Employee': ['ID1', 'ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1','ID1', 'ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2','ID2','ID2','ID2','ID2', 'ID2'],
'MonthYear': ['201708', '201601','201601','201708','201710','201801','201801', '201601', '201601', '201705', '201705', '201705', '201810', '201811', '201705'],
'AbsenceType': ['0210', '0210','0250','0215','0217','0260','0210', '0210', '0210', '0260', '0250', '0215', '0217', '0215', '0250']}

columns = ['Employee','MonthYear','AbsenceType']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df['SickOrInjury'] = df['AbsenceType'].replace({'0210':'Sick', '0215':'Sick', '0217':'Sick', '0250':'Injury', '0260':'Injury'})
df['MonthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MonthYear'], format="%Y%m")
df = df.groupby(['MonthYear', 'Employee', 'SickOrInjury']).count()

# renaming the aggregated (and unique) column
df = df.rename(columns={'AbsenceType': 'EmpAbsCount'})

df = df.unstack(['Employee', 'SickOrInjury'], fill_value=0)
# resampling for monthly values:
df = df.resample('M').sum().stack(['Employee', 'SickOrInjury'])

sns.lineplot(x='MonthYear', y='EmpAbsCount', data=df, hue='Employee', style='SickOrInjury', markers=True, ci=None)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you! that works, I could not wrap my head around stack and unstuck by myself :) Would it also be possible to plot it by daily values, if I use df = df.resample('D').sum().stack(['Employee', 'SickOrInjury'])?

Comment: `resample` will also work with `'D'` as argument but your data doesn't have day information in your example...

Comment: I tried with the days but resample('D') seems to add days where there was no data and just fills it with zero values for SickOrInjury. In the end, because there is too much data (for 3 years), the plot is unclear and only year-month are displayed on Ox (not year-month-day).